# To get group description from AWS Cognito using Java and Postman

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, postman, amazon-cognito

I am trying to get the description of group using getGroup API of AWS Cognito. I want to have the description of group in my JSON object, but it is not fetching the detail. Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at documentation of AWS [HERE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GetGroup.html).

As You can see response contains description of group.

```
  {
   "Group": { 
      "CreationDate": number,
      "Description": "string",
      "GroupName": "string",
      "LastModifiedDate": number,
      "Precedence": number,
      "RoleArn": "string",
      "UserPoolId": "string"
   }
}
```

Please show us Your code, maybe we can find problem there.

Comment: I understand there is an action, How to run this action in postman? whats the URL, body and requestparams? Can u give details pls